# ZF3 correct place to put your api keys

Tags: php, config, zend-framework3, service-locator

I guess I am doing it right because I can overrule the file by development mode but to be sure I ask. What is the right place to store API keys for services I installed through composer. For now I store the keys in the autoload directory inside local.php and receive them through service locator.

For example

```
$config  = $this->serviceLocator->get('Config'); 
var_dump($config['service_name_api']); // Returns api key
```

Is this the right way or should I use another way to access those properties?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best place would be:

```
config/autoload/{config file name you want}.local.php
```

I suggest structure:

```
[
    'keystore' => [
        'api' => [
            // keys array
        ]
    ]
]
```

Repeat I suggest a structure above, you can create your own structure but anyway add

```
config/autoload/{config file name you want}.local.php.dist
```

file that has an example data on it.

Answer (score 1):

That looks like what I would do, though you would need to either provide a default value (in your module configuration), which is not possible in the api keys context, or throw a proper exception in your factory because you don't want to have an `undefined index service_name_api` in a few months :)

Some people also like to have a configuration object, and have a factory just for this object (it helps with managing default values and not crashing). I personally tends to find it a bit too much though, unless your key is reused in many location, in which case you would have the factory test duplicated.

So instead of adding the following to every factory that consumes it

```
if (!isset($config['service_name_api']) || !is_string($config['service_name_api'])) {
    throw new \Exception('No "service_name_api" found in the configuration');
}
```

You could have a simple object

```
final class ServiceNameApiOption
{
    private $key;

    public function __construct(string $apiKey)
    {
        $this->key = $apiKey;
    }

    public function getKey() : string
    {
        return $this->key;
    }
}
```

And then a factory just for that:

```
final class ServiceNameApiOptionFactory
{
    public function __invoke(ContainerInterface $container)
    {
         $config  = $container->get('Config');
         if (!isset($config['service_name_api']) || !is_string($config['service_name_api'])) {
             throw new \Exception('No "service_name_api" found in the configuration');
         }
         return new ServiceNameApiOption($config['service_name_api']);
    }
}
```